# Jsxgraph A working code which generates an error

Tags: error-handling

The following code does what I expect. But tt generates an error which empeaches to add further code. Could somebody explain why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>[sperner Lemma]</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jsxgraph.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./jsxgraphcore.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
  .serif {
    font-family: "Computer Modern", Times, serif;
  }
  
  .sansserif {
    font-family: "Computer Modern Sans", Times, sans-serif;
  }
  
  .monospace {
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: #11ffee00;
    color: #074978;
  }
  
  .shaded {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 12px #888;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
  
  div.Wrapper * {
    color: "red";
  }
  
  #myDIV {
    color: "red";
    background-color: Transparent;
  }
  
  .circle {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: solid 1px #DCDCDC;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(1, 1, 0, 0.6);
    -o-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(1, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-radius: 70px;
  }
  
  .rotated45 {
    transform: rotate(-47deg);
  }
</style>


<script>
  window.MathJax = {
    tex: {
      inlineMath: [
        ['$', '$'],
        ["\\(", "\\)"]
      ],
      displayMath: [
        ['$$', '$$'],
        ["\\[", "\\]"]
      ],
      packages: ['base', 'ams']
    },
    options: {
      ignoreHtmlClass: 'tex2jax_ignore',
      processHtmlClass: 'tex2jax_process'
    }
  };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
</script>

</head>

<body class="serif">
  <center>
    <div id="box1" class="jxgbox" style="width:800px; height:600px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      rougevenitien = '#AE181E';
      peche = '#ffdfbf';
      cadet = '#5F9EA0';
      olivedrab = '#6B8E23';
      vert = "#069E1C";
      monjaune = '#f9f9fb';
      JXG.Options.text.useMathJax = true;

      cadetBlue = "#5F93A0";
      venetianRed = "#c80815";
      grey = "#d9d9d6";
      mauve = "#E2ABBF";
      jauneImperial = "#FAE22F";
      oldPink = "#c77986";
      vertPin = "#01796F";
      wheat = "#F5DEB3";
      lavenderBlush = "#FFF0F5";
      monBleu = "#09ABF1";
      vertEmeraude = "#019875";
      brightTeal = "#01F9C6";
      gold = "#FFD700";
      von = true;
      vno = false;

      var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard("box1", {
        pan: {
          enabled: false
        },
        boundingbox: [0, 8, 10, 0],
        axis: true,
        withLines: false,
        defaultAxes: {
          x: {
            ticks: {
              visible: true
            }
          },
          y: {
            ticks: {
              visible: true
            }
          },
          keepAspectRatio: true
        },
        showNavigation: false,
        showCopyright: false
      });

      var pdc0 = board.create("point", [1, 0.5], {
        size: 6,
        fillColor: venetianRed,
        strokeColor: venetianRed,
        name: "",
        highlight: false
      });
      var pdc1 = board.create("point", [9, 0.5], {
        size: 6,
        fillColor: gold,
        strokeColor: gold,
        name: "",
        highlight: false
      });
      var seg0 = board.create("segment", [pdc0, pdc1], {
        strokeColor: "black",
        highlight: false
      });
      var circ0 = board.create("circle", [pdc0, pdc1.X() - pdc0.X()], {
        visible: false,
        highlight: false
      });
      var circ1 = board.create("circle", [pdc1, pdc1.X() - pdc0.X()], {
        visible: false,
        highlight: false
      });
      var inter0 = board.create("intersection", [circ0, circ1, 1], {
        size: 6,
        fillColor: cadetBlue,
        strokeColor: cadetBlue,
        name: "",
        highlight: false
      });
      var seg1 = board.create("segment", [pdc0, inter0], {
        strokeColor: "black",
        highlight: false
      });
      var seg2 = board.create("segment", [pdc1, inter0], {
        strokeColor: "black",
        highlight: false
      });
      var input0 = board.create('input', [1, 7.5, '4', 'N ='], {
        cssStyle: 'width: 10px'
      });
      board.update();
      var x = (parseFloat(input0.Value()) + 1)


      function rb0(color1, color2) {
        let result;
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) + 0.5) == 1) {
          result = color1
        } else {
          result = color2
        }
        return result;
      };

      circd = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        circd.push(board.create("circle", [pdc0, i * (pdc1.X() - pdc0.X()) / x], {
          visible: true,
          name: 0,
          highlight: false
        }))
      };

      interd = [];

      for (var j = 0; j <= x; j++) {
        rcolor0 = rb0("#c80815", "#5F93A0");
        interd.push(board.create("intersection", [circd[j], seg1], {
          size: 6,
          fillColor: rcolor0,
          strokeColor: rcolor0,
          name: "",
          highlight: false
        }))
      };

      interb = [];
      for (var j = 0; j <= x; j++) {
        rcolor1 = rb0("#c80815", "#5F93A0");
        interb.push(board.create("intersection", [circd[j], seg0], {
          size: 6,
          fillColor: rcolor1,
          strokeColor: rcolor1,
          name: "",
          highlight: false
        }))
      };
    </script> <br/> </center>
</body>

</html>
```